# jQuery ajax function not working no request sent and no error receieved

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have some code which I am using to call `$.ajax`

```
function doajax(url, dataType, data, method, context, callback, block) {
    block = typeof block !== 'undefined' ? block : true;
    if (block) {
        showOverlay();
    }
    var settings = {
        dataType: dataType,
        data: data,
        type: method,
        url: url,
        error: onerror,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { onsuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR, context, callback); }
    };
    $.ajax(url, settings);
    console.log("doajax: called $.ajax");
    return false;
}

function onerror(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log("doajax: error");
    hideOverlay();
    formSpinner.stop();
    var extra = jqXHR.hasOwnProperty("responseJSON") ? jqXHR.responseJSON.error : jqXHR.responseText;
    alert("Error (" + jqXHR.status + ") :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown + " :: " + extra);
}

function onsuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR, context, callback) {
    console.log("doajax: success");
    hideOverlay();
    formSpinner.stop();
    if (data.status === 200 || data.status === 201) {
        hooks[callback](data, context);
    }
    else {
        alert("Error (" + jqXHR.status + ") :: " + textStatus + " :: " + data.error);
    }
}
```

Everything was working ok, but now, there is no request received by the server, and the `Chrome` network window is showing me a `GET 200 OK` regardless of whether it was a `GET` or `POST` request.

In the network tab, there is NO request which goes out for the `url: url` parameter from the `$.ajax settings`, instead I am seeing a request for the current page, which produces the `200 OK` response.

There is no error being thrown, and the success function is also never called.

I have been looking at possible caching issues, however, `POST` requests are never cached so I am unsure what is happening.

EDIT: Added `console.log()` and after performing a UI function which should trigger the `$.ajax()` call the log is showing:

> doajax: called $.ajax

I have also turned on `Log XMLHttpRequests` and I am seeing confirmation that the request does in fact generate but for the current page `url`, not the parameter passed in via the `settings`

Answer: This is an issue with `jQuery` versions. I found there is an old version of `jQuery` being used where I have just integrated this code. When I drop `jQuery 1.11` in on top of my code, it is all working ok.

So the actual problem is that until `jQuery 1.5` there was no support for `$.ajax(url, settings);` and only `$.ajax(settings);` can be used.

I can confirm that both using `jQuery 1.5+` or changing my code to be `$.ajax(settings);` will work and fix the problem.

Comment: Do your self a favor and add some `console.logs()` to the code to see what parts are working and what not.

Comment: its probably upstream...

Comment: Did you set up chrome to log xmlhttprequests?

Comment: @Dwza It comes from the jQuery ajax call....

Comment: nvm, I saw it, my mistake :)

Comment: and its `console.log()` not `console.logs()` sorry :)

Comment: @epascarello where do I check that?

Comment: @Dwza I have had `debugger;` statements in while working through and I have been using this code for a while now and am only seeing the problem today. I will put some `console.log()` statements.

Comment: @epascarello thanks, I have turned it on

Comment: @Dwza Do yourself a favor and add some breakpoints to the lines to see what parts are working and what not.

Comment: @Moshmage What do you want to tell me with that?